Non-parametric and semi-parametric cif
I recently played around with {survival} to get insights into competing risks analyses.
The data used comes with {survival}.
library(survival)
library(ggsurvfit)

mgus2$etime <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, futime, ptime))
event <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, 2*death, 1))
mgus2$event <- factor(event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "pcm", "death"))

I calculated the cumulative incidence function using the non-parametric method and derived the probability of an event or death at time t. 
Confidence intervals for the probabilities can be displayed via summary_mfit2$lower and summary_mfit2$upper.
Further, I plotted the cumulative incidence function:
mfit2 <- survfit(Surv(etime, event) ~ sex, data=mgus2)

summary_mfit2 <- summary(mfit2, times=c(20))

> summary_mfit2
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(etime, event) ~ sex, data = mgus2)

                sex=F 
 time n.risk n.event Pr((s0)) Pr(pcm) Pr(death)
   20    540      93    0.852  0.0175     0.130


                sex=M 
 time n.risk n.event Pr((s0)) Pr(pcm) Pr(death)
   20    621     137    0.818  0.0106     0.171


ggcuminc(mfit2, outcome = c("pcm")) +
           add_confidence_interval()

Next, I gave the semi-parametric approach a shot as follows:
cfit1 <- coxph(Surv(etime, event) ~ sex, mgus2, id=id)

dummy <- expand.grid(sex = c("F", "M"))

csurv <- survfit(cfit1, newdata = dummy)

temp <- summary(csurv, times = c(20))

> temp 
Call: survfit(formula = cfit1, newdata = dummy)

                data 1 
     time    n.risk   n.event  Pr((s0))   Pr(pcm) Pr(death) 
  20.0000 1161.0000  230.0000    0.8668    0.0111    0.1221 

                data 2 
     time    n.risk   n.event  Pr((s0))   Pr(pcm) Pr(death) 
  20.0000 1161.0000  230.0000    0.8388    0.0102    0.1510 

Questions:

Since only one binary covariate (sex) is used, does it make sense to use the semi-parametric approach or should one use the non-parametric approach?
When someone describes the use of cause-specific cox ph regression, is it my understanding that this refers automatically to the semi-parametric approach to estimate the risk (CIF), or am I wrong?
The non-parametric approach provides CIs for the risk at time t. How can these be derived for the semi-parametric approach?
If CIs are derived, how can the semi-parametric object csurv be plotted with confidence intervals? The function ggcuminc() does not work, and using the basic function plot() (which does work) is a mess.



The non-parametric approach allows the survival curves to differ between the sexes. The semi-parametric Cox model assumes the same baseline hazard for both sexes and then estimates the log-hazard difference between the sexes. Either choice is defensible, but the Cox model will be easier to extend to additional predictors.

If someone specifies "cause-specific Cox PH hazard ratios," then the hazard ratios were from a (semi-parametric) Cox model. There can also be fully parametric proportional hazard models, for example based on the Weibull distribution.

You will have to use different software, for example the mstate package, as the survival package doesn't (currently) calculate the variances needed to get standard errors for multi-state Cox models. Section 6.1 of the competing risks vignette says:



One current disadvantage of the survival package is that the Aalen-Johansen curves from a multi-state coxph model currently do not include a variance estimate, whereas those from mstate do have a variance.


As ggcuminc() presumably produces plots via the ggplot2 package, you can construct a data frame that includes information about confidence limits. Those can be added to the base plot at individual time points via geom_errorbar(), shown as lines with geom_line(), or drawn as confidence bands with geom_ribbon(). You might get some ideas from this page. The more curves you show on a plot, the more confusing confidence bands become. I find that displaying confidence intervals at a few representative time points is least confusing.

In response to comments
It's important to distinguish the Aalen-Johansen (AJ) estimates themselves from how inference might be done with them. As Section 2.1 of the competing risks vignette explains, "For the two state alive-dead model the Aalen-Johansen (AJ) estimate has reprised the KM... The [cumulative incidence] is also a special case of the Aalen-Johansen." Unless you move to some other method like the Fine-Gray subdistributional hazard approach, you will be working with an AJ estimate.
In a non-parametric model, "[t]he standard error of the estimates is computed using an infinitesimal jackknife... This is essentially the same algorithm as the robust variance for a Cox model."
In a Cox competing-risks model (Section 3.1 of the vignette), inference is typically done via Wald tests on the coefficient(s) of interest. As noted above, however, the survival package doesn't provide for confidence intervals on the corresponding AJ cumulative-incidence curves.

Thank you. I appreciate your answer! Maybe Q2 was not precise enough: Does the AJ estimator stem from the cause-specific model? Or does someone use the cause-specific model and estimates risk non-parametric?

@geek45 usual practice would be to use the AJ estimate from the cause-specific model. In the non-parametric model there is no common baseline hazard, so the hazard ratio wouldn’t be well defined.

Thank you. What about only one binary covariate in the cause-specific ph regression. Doesn’t it make more sense to use the non-parametric approach to derive CIF? .. As, e.g there is no covariate such as age for which specific predictions need to be estimated. I find it somewhat intransparent as the plots are mainly titled: Cumulative incidence. There is, for instance, one analysis with cause-specific hazards that uses 1-KM for death and AJ for other events with competing risk of death. Thus, i assume, they used “standard ph regression” and non-parametric CIF..

@geek45 for a single binary covariate it's a choice of whether or not you want to assume a shared baseline hazard over time. If you do, choose the Cox model. If not, choose the non-parametric model. In the non-parametric model there won't be a well-defined hazard ratio, but you can use the infinitesimal jackknife (on the AJ estimate) to do inference about the difference. If the data aren't from a randomized trial, however, I'd be skeptical of any survival model with only a single binary covariate, given the risks of omitted-variable bias in survival models.

@geek45 I added to the answer to clarify that all of these can be thought of as AJ estimates; the differences are in how you compare and use them. I suspect that the "one analysis with cause-specific hazards that uses 1-KM for death and AJ for other events with competing risk of death" might not have been correct. It might be an example of what the vignette describes in Section 2.2: "A common mistake with competing risks is to use the Kaplan-Meier separately on each event type while treating other event types as censored."
